# What can be inferred from two datasets using k-means or k-nn

Tags: data-mining, k-means, knn

I am wondering what you could infer using data mining from two large datasets that have similar properties. Say you have two datasets containing detailed information about schools in a country and each dataset belongs to a school stage for a particular year. What sorts of things can you do with these datasets using data mining?

I know how to use and apply the algorithms in pandas but I am having problems with getting the motivation behind the k-means especially.

I know you use the k-means to put the unlabeled data into clusters based on number of factors from the dataset and based on the property values of each data element, they are being placed in one of the clusters created. But then what do you do with these clusters? How can you use them for analysing the data? I read that it can even be used for cleaning the data or relating two datasets to each other, but I'm just having hard time to imagine how would you go about to do these things.

Any help is well appreciated. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do many things with those datasets including:

See which students from a lower stage are more likely to be in which group (successful, unsuccessful etc.) when they reach a higher stage based on some factors

See what factors are affecting the success of the students at different stages (assuming the datasets contain this information)

You can do many different comparisons based on different factors

..and many more. The issue is that it is not really possible to say what can be inferred from your datasets without seeing what information they contain. My suggestion is you should look carefully in two datasets and see if they have some columns that are common and pick the ones that are interest you the most.